# Creating a GUI skeleton in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a Master Frame where I should be able to change the content, while the header and footer should remain the same.  The header and footer are relatively thin.

I probably should do that with 3 Frames: header_frame, footer_frame and central_frame, correct [1]? I need to the header and footer take around 10% and 10%, whereas the center frame fill up the rest.

Should I pack or grid for that[2]? I think pack() is easier in this case, right? If so, how can I do that? Or can it be accomplished by "grid()"[3]? But how would I position all those 3 frame the way I want: 10%, 80% for the center, and 10%[4]?

And also, I've found out that for the **content of my** the central frame it's easier to use grid(). I know I can't combine pack() and grid() within the **same** element. However, I should be able use grid() inside the central frame only, even though I use pack() to create the basic of the 3 frames. Is it correct?[5]

If you could show me an example of what I'm trying to accomplish it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) yes.

(5) yes, inside `Frame` you can use `grid()` and outside `pack()`

(4) you can use `weight` in `grid` to set row size.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

header = tk.Frame(root, bg='green')
content = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
footer = tk.Frame(root, bg='green')

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # 100% 

root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # 10%
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=8) # 80%
root.rowconfigure(2, weight=1) # 10%

header.grid(row=0, sticky='news')
content.grid(row=1, sticky='news')
footer.grid(row=2, sticky='news')

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

If header and footer has some height then

you can use `side` in `pack` to put *footer* at the bottom

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

header = tk.Frame(root, bg='green', height=30)
content = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
footer = tk.Frame(root, bg='green', height=30)

header.pack(fill='both') #, side='top')
content.pack(fill='both')
footer.pack(fill='both', side='bottom')

root.mainloop()
```

or `expand` *content* to use rest of space

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')

header = tk.Frame(root, bg='green', height=30)
content = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
footer = tk.Frame(root, bg='green', height=30)

header.pack(fill='both')
content.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
footer.pack(fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when I create everything all 3 frames via grid like in your 1st example and then am trying  to add a control into the Central frame via pack, it says it's not allowed. why not? can't I use pack inside the Central Frame?